# Нужна ли запятая после вводного слова "так"?

Tags: пунктуация

Как мне кажется, здесь вводное слово не начинает собой обособленного оборота, но почему-то запятой ставить категорически не хочется.

В рамках коллективной экспозиции свои промышленные достижения представили московские организации, так ОАО «...» продемонстрировало безопасный локомотивный объединённый комплекс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Вашем предложении следовало бы разделить его на две части точкой. В этом случае после слова "так" Вам захотелось бы поставить запятую, ибо вводное слово"так" = "например":
"В рамках коллективной экспозиции свои промышленные достижения представили московские организации.  Так, ОАО «...» продемонстрировало безопасный локомотивный объединённый комплекс.

Comment: Да, думала об этом. Просто хотелось узнать, как сделать, если не разделять.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, хотя бы точку с запятой-то поставьте.

...**свои промышленные достижения представили московские организации; *так,* ОАО «...» продемонстрировало**...

Запятая после ТАК в любом случае нужна, как указал **Виктор1799**.